# how to specify width for material 2 bottom sheet in different resolution

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I have page which is divided into two vertical panes. The left and right panes respond to differnt resolutions.

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxFlexFill  fxLayout.xs="column" >
  <div fxFlex="20" class="width" fxFlex.sm="45" fxFlex.md="35" fxFlex.lg ="30" >
      left div  
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="80"  fxFlex.sm="55" fxFlex.md="65" fxFlex.lg ="70">
       //div rendering bottomsheet
  </div>
```

I am opening the bottomsheet like this in my component

```
openBottomSheet() {
   this.closeBottomSheet();
   const config: MatBottomSheetConfig = {
   hasBackdrop: false,
   disableClose: false,
   panelClass: 'bottom-sheet-container',
   direction: 'ltr'
  };
 this.matRef = this._bottomSheet.open(DiagnosticCompanionComponent, config);
}
```

this is bottom-sheet-container class:

```
  .bottom-sheet-container {
    // margin-left: 465px !important;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0px;
       right: 10px;
       width: calc(100vw - 485px) !important;
       min-width: 0% !important;
   }
```

Earlier my left div was having fixed width of '485px' and hence i was able to render my bottom sheet in remaining space. But now as I have made page responsive,I am unable to figure out, how to specify bottom sheet width for different resolutions in angular flex-layout.

Comment: I was bale to solve my problem by writing media queries.

Answer (score 3):

`Angular Material` automatically adds the following classes based on the size of your screen:

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container-medium {
  min-width: 384px;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 128px)
}

.mat-bottom-sheet-container-large {
  min-width: 512px;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 256px)
}

.mat-bottom-sheet-container-xlarge {
  min-width: 576px;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 384px)
}
```

Just add this code to your `styles.css` / `styles.scss` and change the values as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem, by writing media queries as shown below.But i am unsure if this is best appraoch

```
 .bottom-sheet-container {
 // margin-left: 465px !important;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 10px;
   width: 78%;
   @media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px) {
     width : 51%;
    }
   @media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
     width : 62%;
    }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
     width : 67%;
    }

   // width: calc(100vw - 485px) !important;
    min-width: 0% !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: For doing this, You need to apply css at global level instead of component level

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
::ng-deep .mat-bottom-sheet-container{
  min-width: 100vw!important;
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective!